# Is there any z/OS control block with info on job restart specifications

Tags: zos

When submitting a job with JCL like

```
//jobname JOB ,'XXX    ',MSGCLASS=H,
//          CLASS=0,REGION=0M,
//  RESTART=stepname
//  ...
```

is there any place in the control block chains (PSA->TCB->TCT-> ... or
PSA->TCB->JSCB-> ... or something else) where I can find info on, if the
RESTART parameter was explicitly stated on the JOB-card?

Comment: Did you check the SSJS (Job Select SSOB) or the JMR? I think both have bits telling you that restart was requested.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it, and as far as I have tested it, the content of fields does not depend whether the job has a RESTART specification or not.

Comment: I was curious, so I setup a test and dumped the job select SSOB (SSJS) and the JMR pointed to by the SSJS structure with a PER SLIP trap on return from the initiator's Job Select SSI call . In both structures, when I specify RESTART=stepname, the bits SSJSTRS and JMRSTRS are set.  The system does in fact restart the job at the step I specify. I also see that the JES2 $JCT contains the step number of the restarted step in JCTJSSTP, and the actual stepname is in the SJF C/I text if you need it.